# Self supporting a wire by its ends

Tags: structural-engineering

Lets say I want to string a 111ft long antenna wire between 2 trees that are 325ft apart.  I'd have to use some guy rope on the ends to attach the wire ends to branches.  Obviously, I'd want the guy ropes pulled very tight in order to have as much a horizontal run as possible.  What is the smallest size stranded wire that will do this?  And how much tension will be on the guy ropes?

The radio cable attachment would be at the very center and is very lightweight cable, id say maybe 2lbs max at the very center.

Comment: Weight the spool of wire and add a large allowance for wind loading over the years, also see here: https://www.google.com/search?q=bow+and+arrow+antenna+tree

Answer (score 3):

The math involved is well beyond the limitations of my alleged mind, but I did locate a rather [clearly-written paper describing catenary curves](http://astrowww.phys.uvic.ca/%7Etatum/classmechs/class18.pdf). Of particular note is a statement that it is physically impossible to have a horizontal member (rope, cable, chain, etc.) as anything suspended between two points will follow the math.

Your limitation in constructing the antenna will be based on the strength of the wire to be suspended. Using trees as part of the supporting structure would require some flexibility in the construction, as the wind will blow the branches varying the forces on the wire.

If you examine overhead wire powered rail systems, you will note that the required straight wire to provide power is suspended from a catenary curved cable, similar to the construction of a suspension bridge.

The electrical aspects of an electric rail system is not pertinent to this question, but the [website which explains it](https://electricalbaba.com/electric-traction-how-does-electric-traction-work/) also includes a clear image of a catenary supported line:

[image: catenary power line]

The inescapable catenary support has a series of appropriate length *non-conductive* suspenders, which allows the power circuit to maintain a clean horizontal line.

As you are considering an antenna, it's critical to use non-conductive suspension lines and possibly a non-conductive catenary as well. Any emitted power from the antenna would probably be adversely affected if the support wire is metallic.

One might create temporary supports at ground level to string and rig the antenna wire, then use the rope system to place it in the trees.

To attempt an answer of sorts, you would not be able to specify the smallest wire that could handle the tension. The question is more how much tension can the wire you select accept. By using a catenary support design as shown in the image, you can select a much stronger "backbone" and hang almost any lightweight wire, within reason.

Comment: catenaries are awesome